# Invalid form of array reference at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm try to run a code where  OUTF is array(1:20,1:10000)

```
WRITE(7) iy,imd, xlat,xlon,hx,oar(43,li),XCOR,OUTF(2,li),outf(3,li),
 & OUTF(4,li),OUTF(5,li),OUTF(6,li),OUTF(7,li),OUTF(8,li),outf(9,li),
 & OUTF(10,li),OUTF(11,li)
```

and get error

```
  & OUTF(10,li),OUTF(11,li)
   1
```

How to fix it?

Comment: jcecar answer already helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuation line in free-form Fortran is created with an ampersand (`&`) at the **end of line** (ampersand at the beginning of the continuation line is optional - [see link](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Continuation+lines)) as follows:

```
WRITE(7) iy,imd, xlat,xlon,hx,oar(43,li),XCOR,OUTF(2,li),outf(3,li), &
 & OUTF(4,li),OUTF(5,li),OUTF(6,li),OUTF(7,li),OUTF(8,li),outf(9,li), &
 & OUTF(10,li),OUTF(11,li)
```

Or you could simply write:

```
WRITE(7) iy,imd, xlat,xlon,hx,oar(43,li),XCOR,OUTF(2:11,li)
```

No continuation needed.